# Plain text box with placeholder/prompt text in Android

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to create plain text, that shows text "Enter here" but greyed out and when you click on the text box, the displayed text disappears, like how when you open a new tab on Google and it shows "Search Google or type a URL".

I have already created the plain text and a button that display the text when you enter it in the plain text.

I tried to search it online, but I don't know what the term is for it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an `EditText` with a `hint` property

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText

Comment: Thank you, found the hint option on the attribute menu. Didn't realise it was right in front of me.

Comment: @Asura You need to accept the answer if it solve your issue. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)